# play avi, mp4, flv in 1 software

Tags: media-player

I'm looking for a software that can play mp4 (quicktime), flv, and avi, rm (real media). Other criteria is the ability to fast forward and fast rewind.and the ability to play at speeds greater than 1.

Any suggestions? Right now I have 3 software for different types.

Comment: Have you ever tried VLC?

Comment: [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.php?cat=video) doesn't cut it?

Answer (score 6):

Try VLC Media Player. It's a great program with all the codecs built in. It's free and open source, and runs on Mac, Windows and Linux OSes.

If you want to play in Windows Media Center or Windows Media Player, check out the K-Lite Codec Pack. This will enable support for hundreds (?) of media files

Answer (score 3):

Besides the venerable VLC, you should also check out Media Player Classic-HD.

As far as codecs, I prefer Shark's Win7 Codecs.  It's a smaller download, it offers far more customizations, and is less intrusive. For example, there is no "full" or "lite" version of Shark's Win7. It's all there and you can individually turn off components.

Answer (score 0):

I use PotPlayer
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Video-Players/PotPlayer.shtml  
It is able to play pretty much everything, and supports external codecs, so you can install the k-lite http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm 
 (k-lite also comes with media player classic, as an option) and that can play your files too)
Or any other codec pack you might prefer.
VLC is also a viable option, but I dislike the gui, and found that the codecs aren't always able to handle what I throw at it without skipping.